# No matching function for call to pthread_create Objective-C ARC conversion

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

converting my project to ARC but says it can't due to the following error 'No matching function for call to pthread_create'. Here is the code it falls in, happens specifically on the line starting with `pthread create`. How can I fix this? It also says `Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'NSString *' to 'void * _Nullable' for 4th argument` in the sidebar underneath the error.

I've cut off the rest of the function but can provide more detail if necessary.

```
void World::loadWorld(std::string name)
{
    if(doneLoading==0)
    {
    doneLoading=1;
    Resources::getResources->stopMenuTune();
    if(LOW_MEM_DEVICE)
    {
        menu->deactivate();

        Resources::getResources->unloadMenuTextures();
        terrain->allocateMemory();
        terrain->loadTerrain(name,TRUE);
        doneLoading=2;
        hud->fade_out=1;
    }
    else
    {
        terrain->allocateMemory();
        pthread_t foo;
        pthread_create(&foo,NULL,loadWorldThread, nsstring(name));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your error message indicates the 4th argument to `pthread_create` is of type `void *`. Under ARC you cannot simply pass an Obj-C object reference as a `void *` as ARC would is not able to track the reference once it is stored in a C(++) pointer variable, and therefore cannot manage the object's memory.

For situations where an Obj-C reference must be passed into the C(++) world a *bridge cast* can be used to inform ARC how the memory should be managed. However in your case there a better way, just pass the C++ pointer, `name`, without creating an `NSString`. If `loadWorldThread` expects a `std::string` that is the correct thing to do anyway. If it expects an `NSString *` then either:

- modify it to take a `std::string` and do any required conversion to `NSString *` within it; or
- write a small intermediate function which takes a `std::string`, produces an `NSString *` from it, and then calls `loadWorldThread`. Pass this new function to `pthread_create`.

Doing either of the above avoids the use of a bridge cast in the `pthread_create` call to move the Obj-C reference into the C(++) world and out of ARC control; and another bridge cast in `loadWorldThread` (or intermediate function as above) to move it back into the Obj-C world and into ARC control.

**Addendum**

Expanding on the last paragraph, as the method there seems better suited to your situation. First, it is **assumed** that your code:

```
nsstring(name)
```

takes a value of type `std::string` and returns a value of type `NSString`, if it does not then look up how to do this conversion.

After the above expression you have a reference to an `NSString` under ARC control. You cannot simply pass such a reference as a `void *`, you must take it out of ARC's control first and take responsibility for its memory management (but not for long as you will see). You can bridge cast your `NSString *` to a `CFStringRef`:

```
CFStringRef cfName = (__bridge_retain CFStringRef)nsstring(name);
```

You can now pass `cfName`, which is a reference to a heap-allocated `CFString`, as a `void *`.

Now in `loadWorldThread`; which should be declared to take a `void *`, something like `void loadWorldThread(void *arg) { ... }`; you need to bridge cast your `CFStringRef` back to `NSString *` and hands responsibility for its memory management back to ARC:

```
NSString *nsName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)arg;
```

The above is a standard pattern to pass an ARC controlled reference though an anonymous reference (`void *`).

*(Note: the above uses `CFStringRef` to make it clear that you are passing around a reference to a manually managed `CFString`, you can cast directly to `void *` and back again, indeed you will notice that when casting back `arg` was not first cast to a `CFStringRef` to demonstrate this.)*

HTH

Comment: How would I go about doing this? Sorry to ask fr spoonfeeding but I've tried looking it up and can't work it out

Comment: What don't you understand? Assuming you can modify `loadWorldThread` instead of  calling `nsstring(name)` and passing its result to `pthread_create`, instead just pass `name` and inside `loadWorldThread` perform the `nsstring(name)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911474/exc-bad-access-with-cpstring-and-pthread-create-function-how-to-fix-these-funct I've attempted what I think is a fix but this is as far as I've got, any idea what to do?

Comment: First it would be better to edit this question rather than ask a new one, especially as you are trying to follow answer above. In your new code you are passing `&name`, that is not a `std::string` but the address of a variable on the stack. If you cannot pass the `std::string` itself because it is stack allocated (so isn't just a heap pointer which you can pass as `void *`) you *will* need to convert it to a heap allocated string before the call to `pthread_create` - create a `CFString` from it, as that can be passed as a `void *`, then in `loadWorldThread` [cont...]

Comment: [...cont] bridge transfer it to an `NSString` so ARC takes responsibility for its memory management. You'll probably need to read up on bridge casts, it is *essential* that you understand the memory management semantics here or you'll easily get into trouble.

Comment: I've attempted in a few places to convert `name` into a `CFString` but each time I try to do it it is saying `No matching function for call to 'CFStringCreateWithCString'` wherever I try to do it. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you imported the Core Foundation header? As to other ways, you can create an `NSString` using your existing method to do so and then do a bridge transfer cast to get a `CFStringRef` (or just a `void *` directly, the referenced object will still be a `CFString`).

Comment: OK, I've added an addendum, hopefully that will help you understand this better.